# Finding Eigenvectors when we have lots of zeroes

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-bundles

\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 8 \\
\end{array}

I have $\lambda_1=8$ and $\lambda_2=0$ but cannot find $V_1$ or $V_2$

I try

\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0  \\
0 & 8-\lambda \\
\end{array} 
Sub in $\lambda_1$
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0  \\
0 & \lambda-8 \\
\end{array} 
Now
\begin{array}{cc}
-8 & 0  \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array} 
So what is V_1? i dont understand. thank you much

Comment: where do you setup your eigenvector equation? You've presumably solved for the eigenvalues $0,8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just solve $Av=0$ and $Av=8v$ respectively. But tha is trivial: in a basis of eigenvectors, the matrix will become a diagonal matrix, with the eigenvalues as diagonal elements. And you matrix is *already* diagonal. Hence the eigenvalues are $0$  and $8$, and the eigenvectors are $e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $\enspace e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: However if we swap the eigenvalues from 0 and 8, to 8 and 0, do we not swap the eigenvectors too?

Comment: That's perfectly right.

Comment: This is an amazing "trick" - thank you so much